# How to export my pdf file names from about 500 folders?

Tags: batch-file, export, subdirectory

Suppose on my Windows machine I have a folder named `root`. Inside this folder I have about 500 subfolders named `John-doe`, `Sara-smith`, `Nicola-sheperd`, etc. Inside each folder I have about 6-7 files with different extensions such as `.png`,`.jpg` `.pdf`, `.tex`, `.idx`, `.txt`, `.aux`, etc. Also note that there may be two or more `pdf` files inside each folder but **only** one of them is the same name as its folder.
Now I want to export the `pdf` file names which are the same name as their folders from these 500 folders and import them into a `mypdfnames.tex` file in the `root` folder like below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\include{John-doe/John-doe.pdf}
\include{Sara-smith/Sara-smith.pdf} 
\include{Nicola-sheperd/Nicola-sheperd.pdf}
...
\end{document}
```

**How can I do This?**
I'm new in batch files, so please provide me with a complete code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script which could become a skeleton for your own solution:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
@SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem full path to "root" directory 
set "myroot=D:\bat\StackOverflow\files\root"
set "myextn=txt"

    rem loop through "*.%myextn%" files (recurse subfolders)
For /R "%myroot%" %%G in (*.txt) do (

      rem find out last item in path
  for /F "tokens=*" %%H in ( "%%~dpG.") do (

        rem is filename==foldername.txt? 
    if /i "%%~nxG"=="%%~nxH.%myextn%" (
         rem redirect next echo: >>"%myroot%\mypdfnames.tex"
      echo(\include{%%~nxH/%%~nxG}
    ) else (
        rem sample only
      echo( omitted  %%~nxG # %%~nxH.%myextn%
    ) 
  )
)
@ENDLOCAL
goto :eof
```

Explained by `rem` comments in the code. Change  `myroot` (path) and `myextn` (extension) variables and add further recording to the `"%myroot%\mypdfnames.tex"` file.

Resources:

- `FOR` - [Loop commands](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- `~` - [Parameter modification](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- `>>` - [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Output:

```
=>dir /b /s D:\bat\StackOverflow\files\root\*.txt
D:\bat\StackOverflow\files\root\Ian-ionescu\Ian-ionescuY.txt
D:\bat\StackOverflow\files\root\Ian-ionescu\Nicola-sheperd.txt
D:\bat\StackOverflow\files\root\John-doe\John-doe.txt
D:\bat\StackOverflow\files\root\John-doe\John-doeA.txt
D:\bat\StackOverflow\files\root\Nicola-sheperd\Nicola-sheperdX.txt
D:\bat\StackOverflow\files\root\Sara-smith\Sara-smith.txt
D:\bat\StackOverflow\files\root\Sara-smith\Sara-smithZ.txt

=>D:\bat\StackOverflow\28551216.bat
 omitted  Ian-ionescuY.txt # Ian-ionescu.txt
 omitted  Nicola-sheperd.txt # Ian-ionescu.txt
\include{John-doe/John-doe.txt}
 omitted  John-doeA.txt # John-doe.txt
 omitted  Nicola-sheperdX.txt # Nicola-sheperd.txt
\include{Sara-smith/Sara-smith.txt}
 omitted  Sara-smithZ.txt # Sara-smith.txt
```